# Load a video in separate div, using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, video-streaming

Ok, I am bugging on this for 2nd day already, and it should be really simple... but it's not working.

I am trying to load a video in a separate `div`, when a link from a nested list (in another `div`) is clicked.

Here's the 2 divs:

```
    <div id="mediaWindow">

    </div>
    <div id="treeviewMenu" runat="server">
        <ul id="LinkedList1" class="LinkedList">
            <li>Installation
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="javascript: void(0)" class="video">
                        <img src="play_icon.png" alt="play_video_icon" title="Video tutorial" />
                        Startup</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript: void(0)" class="video">
                        <img src="play_icon.png" alt="play_video_icon" title="Video tutorial" />
                        Getting there</a></li>
                    <li>
.....
```

And the jQuery that I have:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".video").click(function(event) 
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).html();
            $("#mediaWindow").html('<video width="640" height="360" controls><source src="'+url+'" type="video/mp4" /></video>');
        });
    });
    </script>
```

I also tried doing it with a single static link to a video (instead of the `url` thingy), just of testing purposes, but it doesn't work again.

I also tried statically loading the video into the div, with the `<video>` tag and it worked. But not in the dynamic way through the links.

I have no clue where the problem is...

[**UPDATE: I made a jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fW3yE/4/) - it doesn't load the video (because cannot access the file from *jsfiddle*), but it loads the video window. So is it possible that I somehow don't get linked to the jQuery library? Although I have included it as source in the tag.

P.S. The video should be loaded from the local machine, but not from the Internet.

Comment: @Alvaro - what is a "fiddle" ? O.o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't really seen before the include library to be written directly like you did `<script src="jquery library here">...` 
And it's actually not working because with the first line where you write the `src=`, you're just including the library, thus in your case you didn't surround the actual code with `<script>` tags, but only included the library.

Try to separate it and then enclose the code into other `<script>` tags. Like that:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".video").click(function (е) {
                е.preventDefault();
                var url = this.href;
                $("#mediaWindow").html('<video width="640" height="360" controls><source src="' + url + '" type="video/mp4" /></video>');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Furthermore it might be confusing, the way you wrote it, if you have to change the include library in future.

Then just have the HTML like that:

```
<li>
<a href="testVideo.mp4" class="video">
<img src="play_icon.png" alt="play_video_icon" title="Video tutorial" />
Startup</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `url` which you are trying to specify is not mentioned anywhere. Clicking on the `a` will give the entire `html`, including the image tag. This is not what you need. Specify the url in the `href` to the `a` like so:

`<a href="video/yourVideo.mp4" class="video">...</a></li>`

In your javascript:

`var url = $(this).attr('href');` instead of `var url = this.href;`

Comment: In the jsfiddle that I made it doesn't load the video (because cannot access the file from jsfiddle), but it loads the video window. So is it possible that I somehow don't get linked to the jQuery library? Although I have included it as source in the tag.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Do you have a debugger?

Comment: Yeah, I am using Chrome.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35987/discussion-between-syspect-and-aashray)

Comment: Try using this instead: `<iframe width="400" height="400" src="'+url+'?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Comment: I have tried with iframe in the beginning. There's no difference. I get the same results.

Comment: Then I the problem might have something to do with the path of the video file.

Comment: Well, as I said, with the html like this: `<li><a href="testVideo.mp4" class="video">...</a></li>` and no matter how I change the js code - I always download the video, instead of showing it in the browser. When I put `href="javascript: void(0)"` - nothing happens.

Comment: I think I fixed it. Instead of passing it in the `href` attribute, pass it in the `name` attribute of the `<a>` tag. Put `href` back to what it was before.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to append HTML content to any div or other element y u are not using .append?
like this

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".video").click(function(event) 
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).html(); //this will not work
            $("#mediaWindow").append('<video width="640" height="360" controls><source src="'+url+'" type="video/mp4" /></video>');
        });
    });
    </script>
```

also $(this).html(); is not what you need you will have to use innerHTML

Comment: I tried testing just for the `.append` (by putting directly the video url, instead of using the `var`) and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Just call "load" method of "video" tag whenever dynamically assigning video source.

Also you need to change `var url = $(this).html();` to `var url = this.href;`

and change `<li><a href="javascript: void(0)" class="video">` to `<li><a href="testvideo.mp4" class="video">`

[Here's a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fW3yE/8/)

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".video").click(function(event) 
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = this.href; // Optionally you can also use -> $(this).attr('href') 
        $("#mediaWindow").html('<video width="640" height="360" controls><source src="'+url+'" type="video/mp4" /></video>');
        $("#mediaWindow video").get(0).load(); //Just make a call to load() method
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<li>Installation
    <ul>
        <li><a href="vid.mp4" class="video">  <!-- Change href -->
            <img src="play_icon.png" alt="play_video_icon" title="Video tutorial" />
            Startup</a></li>
        ...
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Ok, but right now I have in the html like this: `<li><a href="testVideo.mp4" class="video">...</a></li>` and no matter how I change the js code - I always download the video, instead of showing it in the browser. When I put `href="javascript: void(0)"` - nothing happens. 
I don't know whether my mistake is in the html or in the js... I'm just lost.

Answer (score 0):

The url should not work, you'll get only the link element.

try the code below:

```
$(".video").click(function(event) 
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = this.href;
        $("#mediaWindow").html('<video width="640" height="360" controls><source src="'+url+'" type="video/mp4" /></video>');
    });
```

and your link should look like this :

```
<a href="yourvideourl.mp4" class="video">
```

Comment: I now have connection to the video, but it gets downloaded, instead of  being loaded into the div.
I also tried using `<iframe width="640" height="360" src="'+url+'?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>` instead of the `<video></video>` tags, and I still have the same effect.